# jQuery selector, and a bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select all images on my page and attach a function to the mouseover event. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmd8h/) showing you what I have so far. At the bottom of the JavaScript section, you can see that I am running the same code twice, once for each image. It seems to me that I should be able to use the .each() function here, but I've tried to do it and can't get it to work. Here are the two duplicate calls I want to turn into one:

```
$("#gen").one('mouseover', function() {  runTransfer('gen'); return false; });
$("#bo").one('mouseover', function() { runTransfer('bo'); return false; });
```

FYI, there is also a bug here (different part of the code) that I'm trying to solve...but only one question at a time. :)

Comment: FYI Instead of **passing** a callback function to the `.effect` you are **executing** it. Change your code to `$("#"+imgID).effect("transfer", options, 1000, function(){afterTransfer(imgID);});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question literally, you can just use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#gen, #bo").one('mouseover', function() {  
    runTransfer(this.id); 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the images a class and then select on the class?

HTML:

```
<img class="addEventToMe" src="..." alt="..."/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".addEventToMe").each(function(elm) {
    elm.one('mouseover', function() {  runTransfer('gen'); return false; });
}
```

Comment: Each image already has a class, which is positioning it on the page. I don't think I can use your suggestion because each of my images needs a unique class.

Comment: Your images can only have one unique class assigned to them?  Isn't that the purpose of the id attribute?

Comment: Maybe...I'm not a CSS expert. :) The images need to be absolutely positioned on the page with x/y coords., and I was using CSS classes for this.

Comment: @karim79 has the right answer.  I don't know jQuery that well, I guess.  But you can have multiple classes on an element without hindering your styling.  Just add something like 'addEventToMe' to each element and in karim79's answer change '#gen, #bo' to '.addEventToMe'.

Comment: What I was really looking for was a way to avoid changing my code (the jQuery, not the HTML) every time I add an image to the page. Both your and karim79's answers don't give me that. But they do shorten my code quite a bit, so I'll leave it alone. :)

Comment: If you use the class method, you don't have to change the JavaScript at all when you add a new image to the page.  You just need to make sure and add the same class to each new image you add to the page.  That shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to do the trick:

```
$.each(['gen','bo'],function(i,id){$('#'+id).one('mouseover',function(){
   runTransfer(id);
})})
```